# Apex Cascading [dependent] Dropdown Lists

Tags: apex, visualforce

OK.  I've been staring at this for hours and referring back to this post ([How to make a Cascading (Dependent) Select List (Drop Down) in a Data Table in VisualForce?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11588/how-to-make-a-cascading-dependent-select-list-drop-down-in-a-data-table-in-v)).  I can't get this working.  I am trying to get so that the user selects an animaltype (dog, cat, fish, hamster) and then the breeds dropdown is re-rendered with the breeds for that animal type i.e., if you select dog, the breed list would read pug, bassett hound, etc.  The code I've got is below -- I've tried a few variations.  Thanks -- KMT

Here is the Apex class:

```
public class CreateOrder{
public list<LineItem__c> lineitemsToInsert {get;set;}
public Order__c getOrder() {
    if(order == null) order = new Order__c();
    return order;
}

public LineItem__c getLineItem() {
    lineitem = new LineItem__c(Order__c = order.id);
    return lineitem;
}
//Select list for animal types [Parent List]
public Set<SelectOption> getTypeOptions() {

Set<SelectOption> options = new Set<SelectOption>();

    for (animal__c animal : [select type__c, description__c from animal__c order by description__c] )
    {
        options.add(new SelectOption(animal.type__c, animal.description__c));
    }
    return options;
}
//Select lists for animal type > breed [Child List]
public List<SelectOption> getBreedOptions() {
List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

    for (animal__c animal : [select breed__c, Name from animal__c WHERE type__c = :lineitem.type__c ] )
    {
        options.add(new SelectOption(animal.Name, animal.breed__c));
    }
    return options;
}

}
```

Here is the VF page:

```
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!lineitemsToInsert}" var="lineitem" id="newLI">
     <apex:column headerValue="Animal Type" >
         <apex:selectList size="1" id="animaltype" styleClass="animaltype" value="{!lineitem.type__c}">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!TypeOptions}"/>
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="breeds"/>
         </apex:selectList>
        <apex:variable var="rowNumber" value="{!rowNumber + 1}" />
     </apex:column>
     <apex:column headerValue="Breed" >
         <apex:selectList size="1" id="breeds" styleClass="breeds" value="{!lineitem.breed__c}" >
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!BreedOptions}"/>
         </apex:selectList>
        <apex:variable var="rowNumber" value="{!rowNumber + 1}" />
     </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Comment: What's your variable "rowNumber" for ?  You've got it defined twice, once in each list.